# sample SoftKeyboard deleting letters when typing a number

Tags: java, android

I'm android's beginner developer
I downloaded source code for sample SoftKeyboard

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/

and run it in android studio
everything is fine....but

-when Typing a letter/letters , and switching to Symbol Keyboard , and type a number , the previous letter/letters Typed is Removed.

how to fix this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the `handleCharacter()` method in `SoftKeyboard.java`. Correct it like this:

```
private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        if (isInputViewShown()) {
            if (mInputView.isShifted()) {
                primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
            }
        }
        if (isAlphabet(primaryCode) && mPredictionOn) {
            mComposing.append((char) primaryCode);
            getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
            updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
            updateCandidates();

        }

        //The following line was moved out of the else clause
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                    String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
}
```

Comment: thats work perfectly :)
now i have other problems...

-the keyboard work only for android 4.4 and above...
how to make it work for 2.3 and above ??

-how to make the keyboard set to default keyboard automatic when install it in any device ?

Comment: Android 2.3 is API level 9. If you use gradle, write `compileSdkVersion 9` to your buildscript and then you can see which classes are not available for 2.3 yet. You need to rewrite some code in this case. It might be easier to follow another tutorial, like [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) to create keyboard for 2.3. *** You cannot set it to default when you install it, only the user can set it. You can only display information to the user on istallation, showing how he/she can set it to default.

Comment: Actually you should not ask questions in comments. You should post them as new questions on the site. Also, if my post solved your initial problem, please accept it as answer by clicking the grey tick.

Comment: yeah i know about "accept the answer"....
thank you for the information about the keyboard

Comment: there is another problem...can you look at it ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499084/sample-softkeyboard-double-letters