# Sample SoftKeyboard double letters

Tags: java, android

I'm android's beginner developer , I downloaded source code for sample SoftKeyboard

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-2.3.3_r1.1/samples/SoftKeyboard

First i had problem which is

"When Typing a letter/letters , and switching to Symbol Keyboard , and type a number , the previous letter/letters Typed is Removed"

i fixed it by removing `else` from method `handleCharacter()` in `SoftKeyboard.java`

```
private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        if (isInputViewShown()) {
            if (mInputView.isShifted()) {
                primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
            }
        }
        if (isAlphabet(primaryCode) && mPredictionOn) {
            mComposing.append((char) primaryCode);
            getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
            updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
            updateCandidates();

        }

        //The following line was moved out of the else clause
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                    String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
}
```

but now i have another problem......

When typing letter then press space or delete , This letter doubled(ex: a > aa).